# Facebook SDK login not receiving any callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am not receiving any callback from facebook after providing permission to the app. App just opens fb browser, asks for permission and then gets stuck at a page. My fb App has single sign-in on and it is active for general public use. I have also provided my bundle identifier there.

You can view my AppDelegate configuration here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication]) {
        NSLog(@"User is logged In already");
        
    }else{
        NSLog(@"User is not logged In already");
        
    }

    //return YES;
    
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

#pragma mark - Social callback Delegates
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
            openURL: (NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation: (id)annotation {
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL urlStatus;
    NSString *socialNetwork = [defaults objectForKey:@"socialNetwork"];
    if([socialNetwork isEqualToString:@"google"])
    {
        urlStatus = [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                           sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                  annotation:annotation];
    }
    else if([socialNetwork isEqualToString:@"facebook"])
    {
        urlStatus = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                   openURL:url
                                                         sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                                annotation:annotation];
    }
    return urlStatus;
}
```

My login method can be seen below:

```
-(void) loginWithFacebook
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [defaults setObject:@"facebook" forKey:@"socialNetwork"];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error || result.isCancelled)
        {
            // Process error
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
            
        }
        
        else
        {
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
            {
                // Do work
                isValid = YES;
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginWithFacebook" sender:self];
            }
        
        }
    }];
}
```

Given below are the images of `.plist` and linked libraries. [image: configurations]

[image: plist]
URL Identifier is not present in the screenshot but I have added it.
Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? Or What might be missing?

Answer (score 2):

just check this 2methods

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{


    [FBAppEvents activateApp];

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{

    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];

}
```

Comment: If you saw my appdelegate file, you will see I have already done [FBAppEvents activateApp];. As for [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];, FB shows [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                   openURL:url
                                                         sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                                annotation:annotation]; to be written there

Comment: Anyways it doesn't enter - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation. It doesn't enter any block after that

Comment: that mean your url schemes is wrong. verify that or try to create new app in facebook

Comment: Url Schemes is alright as you can see in the screenshot. Can you tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: I have done that. They are same. Same fb id. And I have also added the bundle identifier on the app

Comment: then your login method have issue

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0 check this link for Using Custom Login UIs

Comment: Login method is also provided in the question. Please refer to it and I'd be glad if you could point out some anomaly rather than guessing the problem. Try actually reading the data provided. Thank you

Comment: yeah i tried same code provided by you , same issue here. so please try other code for login